# Passing a variable into SQL string

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm modifying someone else's showershell script that's used within our database to try and have it do some extra steps behind the scenes: reject code, location code, and start date.
It starts by asking for 3 values to pass as variables, but I want to add 2 additional values using a dictionary based on the location code.  I don't want to share the entire batch - I know it works without this one specific part, but I'll include enough to illustrate my point.

The issue is with the variables $AREA1 and $AREA2 - these are what I'm trying to add.
The "parameters" are being injected using one way where it asks for the user to supply them but i don't want the user to supply these, they're supposed to be a lookup.
For instance, if the LOC was 5300 then AREA1 should be 101 and AREA 2 should be 111.

```
param(
    [ImdsParameter(FullName = "REJ_CODE", Description = "Enter a 4 digit reject code to filter the data.  Will not run without one.", Length = 4)]
    [string] $REJ,
    [ImdsParameter(FullName = "LOC", Description = "The Location code you want to run this against. Example 5300.", Length = 4)]
    [string] $LOC,
    [ImdsParameter(FullName = "STDTE", Description = "Start date. This is the start date from how back to run the report. Example 2021-01-01", Length = 10)]
    [string] $STDTE
)

$areaStart = @{ 
5300    =   101 ;
5304    =   112 ;
5305    =   123 ;
5306    =   134 ;
//there’s well over 100 of these
}

$areaEnd   = @{ 
5300    =   111 ;
5304    =   122 ;
5305    =   133 ;
5306    =   144 ;
//same
}

$AREA1 = $areaStart.Get_Item($LOC)
$AREA2 = $areaEnd.Get_Item($LOC)

$jobSql = @"

  SELECT TB1.dataitem1,
       TB1. Dataitem2,
       TB1. Dataitem3,
       TB2. Dataitem1
    FROM firstTable AS TB1 INNER JOIN secondTable AS TB2
    ON TB1. dataitem = TB2. dataitem
    WHERE TB1.LOCATION = @LOC AND TB2.AREA BETWEEN '$($AREA1)' AND '$($AREA2)'

"@

$edbms = Get-Rdms -SQL $jobSql -Parameters @{LOC = $LOC;  REJ = $REJ; STDTE = $STDTE;  }
$edbms | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

EDIT: I need to add that the script will run, but returns no data.  If I just plug the SQL in with all the values manually, it will run just fine.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think I might have figured out my issue.  I think the values in the SQL are being treated as strings while the values in the dictionaries are being treated as numbers... I will need to test that out.

Comment: Yep that fixed it.  After hours of trying many different thing it ended up being the most simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the SQL were being treated as strings while the values in the dictionaries were being treated as numbers.

I changed this:

```
5300    =   101 ;
5304    =   112 ;
5305    =   123 ;
5306    =   134 ;
```

To this:

```
'5300'    =   '101' ;
'5304'    =   '112' ;
'5305'    =   '123' ;
'5306'    =   '134' ;
```

And it provided the data expected.

Comment: Could you please update and confirm if it was data side or powershell side that was an issue. Thanks